# Boost.Phoenix: problems when using extra arguments in assignment expression

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

Currently I'm playing around with the Boost.Phoenix functional programming library, to create anonymous functors. I'm stumbled across a problem with the assignment operator expression, when using read only arguments in the functor evaluation:

```cpp
using boost::phoenix::arg_names::_1;
int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0;
(_1 + 1)(a); // OK
(_1 + 1)(a, 0); // OK
(_1 + 1)(a, 0, 1); // OK
// but...
(_1 = 1)(a); // OK
(_1 = 1)(a, 0); // OK
(_1 = 1)(a, 0, 1); // ERROR: read-only variable is not assignable
(_1 = 1)(a, b, 0); // ERROR
(_1 = 1)(a, b, c); // OK
```

Especially, I don't understand why the expression `(_1 = 1)(a, 0)` works fine, but adding one more constant argument, the compilation crashes. Any idea what's going on and how to solve this?

I tried Boost 1.56.0 and 1.60.0, with compilers gcc-4.8.1 and clang-3.4.

Comment: It seems like you need to use [`#define BOOST_PHOENIX_PERFECT_FORWARD_LIMIT 4`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IAEw3sywSgdgthlK) (This will of course postpone the error until you use 4 arguments).
I don't have any idea why it's by default limited to 3 but there is probably a good reason.

Comment: Wow, that's it!! Changing the forward limit to 4 solved my problem. I really had to look deep in the details section of the core implementation of boost phoenix to find the corresponding part and the file, where the limit is set to 3. The reason may be that perfect forwarding is only emulated by adding all permutations of argument cv qualifiers. Thus, the list of permutations increases exponentially when increasing the forwarding limit.